# How to get the region of next line in SublimeText 2 API

Tags: python-2.7, sublimetext2

I'm writing an plugin for Sumblime Text,

I have no idea to get the following lines' region.

I can get the array of regions be the next command,

```
except_regions = self.view.find_all('except') :
```

The region is an tuple (78,89) means start of region and end of region.

But I want to get the following lines' region, the region of **i'm line 1** and **i'm line 2**

Thanks

Sample

```
  except:
   i'm line 1
   i'm line 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# get current line number
row, _ = self.view.rowcol(except_region.a)
# get next line's starting point
next_row_starting = self.view.text_point(row + 1, 0)
# get the whole next line
next_row_region = self.view.full_line(next_row_starting)
print(self.view.substr(next_row_region))
```